# InFix to Prefix method class

Tags: java, class, methods, prefix, infix-notation

I'm trying to pinpoint the error in my prefix calculator class but i'm having trouble doing so.

The expected output should be something like this:
InFix: "2+4" (for example)
PostFix: "24+"
PreFix: " 24" (here is the error)

Here is the class that calculates the prefix:

```
public class PreEva {
private String prefijo;
private String iString;

public PreEva(String iString){
    int longitud = iString.length(); //kinda redundant
    char p1[]=new char[longitud], p2[]=new char[longitud];
    prefijo="";
    int contp1=0, contp2=0;

    for(int i=longitud-1;i>=0;i--){
        char tmp=iString.charAt(i);
        switch(tmp){
            case '^':case')':
                if(contp2<=0){      //If p2 is empty, inputs the operator
                    p2[contp2]=tmp;
                    contp2++;
                    }
                else{
                    p2[contp2]=tmp;
                    contp2++;
                }break;
            case '/':case '*':
                if(contp2<=0){      //If p2 is empty, inputs the operator
                    p2[contp2]=tmp;
                    contp2++;
                }
                else{
                    if(p2[contp2-1]=='^'){
                        while(p2[contp2]-1=='^'){
                            for(int j=contp2; j>0; j--){    //Passes to p1
                                if(p2[contp2-1]==p2[contp2-2]){
                                    contp2=j-1; 
                                    j=0;
                                }
                                else{
                                    p1[contp1]=p2[j-1];
                                    contp1++;
                                }
                                contp2++;
                            }
                            p2[contp2]=tmp;
                            contp2++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        p2[contp2]=tmp;
                        contp2++;
                    }
                }break;
            case '+':case '-':              
                if(contp2<=0){          //Ifthere's nothing in p2, inputs the operator
                    p2[contp2]=tmp;
                    contp2++;
                }
                else{
                    if(p2[contp2-1]==')'||p2[contp2-1]=='+'||p2[contp2-1]=='-'){
                        p2[contp2]=tmp;
                        contp2++;
                    }
                    else{
                        while(!(p2[i-1]==')'||p2[i-1]=='+'||p2[i-1]=='-')){
                            for(int j=contp2; j>0; j--){    //Paso a p1
                                if(p2[contp2-1]==p2[contp2-2]){
                                    contp2=j-1;
                                    j=0;
                                }
                                else{
                                    p1[contp1]=p2[j-1];
                                    contp1++;
                                }
                                contp2++;
                            }
                            p2[contp2]=tmp;
                            contp2++;
                        }
                    }
                }break;
            case '(':
                if(contp2<=0){              //If there is nothing adds to p2
                    p2[contp2]=tmp;
                    contp2++;
                }
                else{
                    for(int j=contp2; j>0; j--){    //To p1
                        if(p2[contp2-1]==')'){      //If the one under tmp is ')', drops the counter(subtracs from counter i believe is more accurate)
                            contp2=j-1;
                            j=0;
                        }
                        else{
                            p1[contp1]=p2[j-1];
                            contp1++;
                        }
                    }
                }break;
            default:p1[contp1]=tmp;          
            contp1++;
            break;
        }

    }
    for(int i=longitud-1; i>=0 ;i--){
        prefijo=""+prefijo+""+p1[i];
    }
 }

/* Retornar Resultado */
public String getOS(){
    return prefijo;
}
```

If anyone has a suggestion on how to improve my code or correct this error is well appreciated!

Thx in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this is supposed to be doing. And I can't read the comments, can you explain what it's supposed to do with more detail?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the comments were in spanish. Gonna edit that now what this code is supposed to do is take an String and calculate its prefix expression and save the prefix expression in the String "prefijo".

Comment: And how do you decide what a prefix is? Is there some specific expression language? Or your own definition?

Comment: As for improvements, can you make the method return the result and make only one object / make method static. don't see the need to create a new object each time you want to do this calculation?

Comment: Actually i believe my english is not the best. It's a mathematical expression in his Infix notation that gets "converted" to it's Prefix notation. And i know i have some redundancies in the code. I'm correcting them right now.
btw thanks for the fast support

Comment: "-24", "+3489", "+63*45", "+3^62" I think

Comment: So the problems I'm getting are due to indexes in arrays begin referenced incorrectly. Have you thought about using stacks instead?

Comment: Yes that would be the best way to solve it or using binary trees i believe but still don't know that much to implement them correctly